# BSE/NSE quote in PHP

Tags: php

I want to display NSE/BSE quote in my PHP website. please let me know what I have to do, if I get the webservices for this then how to use it in PHP.
Please help

Comment: some financial crap i guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse their data from their web sites:

1. First select a page that contains your required data:

   for example: http://www.bseindia.com/mktlive/mktwatch.asp
2. Now parse data using [simple html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
3. Now store extracted data into your database.
4. Now show your data in your website using your database
5. You can code a script that can update your database on daily bases.

Answer (score 3):

NSE/BSE refers to national/bombay stock exchange of india. I think you could look at http://www.programmableweb.com/ if any such api is available.

You can look at http://mayanks.blogspot.com/2009/09/api-for-bse-shares-data-in-india.html for ruby gem called BseQuote.